# React access child variable from parent

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I have `Parent` and child component `Map` for map. I'm assigning leaflet.js to the `leafMap` variable inside `Map` and I can call `leafMap` methods from inside `Map`.
But how can I call 'map' methods from Parent?

```
Parent
  Map
    leafMap = L.map("map", {center: [0,0], zoom: 9});
```

Comment: You could do it easily if you use react leaflet libray either using HOC or hooks